# How to capture argument in Mockito Dart version

Tags: unit-testing, dart, mockito

I am trying to catch argument passes to a function and then make some assertions if one of the argument's property is equal to specific value.

Unfortunately an object is passed, therefore I can not just make a quick assertion according to official docs.

```
cat.eatFood("Fish");
expect(verify(cat.eatFood(captureAny)).captured.single, ["Fish"]);
```

I want to achieve something as shown if this pseudocode;

```
cat.eatFood(fridge);
expect(verify(cat.eatFood(captureAny)).captured.single, fridge.milk == "Milk");
```

or I just wont to store the argument fridge elsewhere.

Comment: `expect(verify(cat.eatFood(captureAny)).captured.single.milk, "Milk");`?

Comment: I got an error TestFailure (No matching calls. All calls: ...)

Comment: I wanted also to write it to the variable.
`var captured =
          verify(cat.eatFood(captureAny)).captured.first;`

Comment: It works for me, as does `var captured =           verify(cat.eatFood(captureAny)).captured.first;`.  Please post a reproducible example and the exact error message.

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem. You were correct. Thanks for your help. This is the working code:

   `var verification = verify(mockedSrv.send(captureAny));
      expect(verification.captured[0].name, expectedName);
      expect(verification.captured[0].isFast, false);`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
verify(
  cat.eatFood(captureThat(equals("fish"))),
).called(1);
```

Check out more examples at: https://pub.dev/packages/mockito/example

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Option 1

```
final verification = verify(mockedSrv.send(captureAny));
expect(verification.captured[0].milk, "Milk");
```

Option 2

```
expect(verify(mockedSrv.send(captureAny)).captured.single.milk, "Milk");
```